# Route two parameter in codeiginter

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I have try to route my url in codeiginter like this.

```
$route['apps/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'apps/index/$1/$2';
```

because I want the url

```
domain.com/apps/parameter1/parameter2
```

This is my controller code

```
<?php
if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No Directory');
    class Apps extends CI_Controller{

        public function index($app_id=null, $result_id=null){
.....
        }

    }
```

but it does't work can anyone help me what wrong with my rout url. I use Codeiginter 3.x

Comment: If you have any concrete route that is starting with `$route['apps/something...']`, that exact route has to be set beforehand. Also, add constructor method, doesn't hurt. How is not working, what happens?

Comment: if I don't use route it like this:
http://nop70.com/apps/index/param1/param2/
I use all
1 no parameter
http://nop70.com/apps/index/
2 have only one parameter to show single app
http://nop70.com/apps/index/param1
and one more to show all result of that app:
http://nop70.com/apps/index/param1/param2
but I want to remove index just kep the url like this
http://nop70.com/apps/
http://nop70.com/apps/param1/param2/
http://nop70.com/apps/param1/param2/

Comment: You have to assign first routes too and to do that before using wild card route.

Comment: Your code works for me, so it's something beyond this code. What happens if you go to `domain.com/index.php/apps/parameter1/parameter2` ??

Comment: @Brain Gottier I try to route like this: 
`$route['apps/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'apps/index/$1/$2';`
but when I try to access the url:
domain.comapps/: this url OK
domain.comapps/parameter1/: this url 404 not found
domain.com/apps/parameter1/parameter2: this url OK
noted index.php hasbeen remove by httaccess:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]`